# How to make an Invisible / Hidden Cocoa Application

Tags: cocoa, macos, service, invisible

I want to develop a application like http://orbicule.com/undercover/ or
http://hiddenapp.com/.

I know how I could do that for windows but I have totally no clue, what kind
of approach I would need for mac os x, cocoa/xcode.

Is there anything I should be aware of when building applicatons / background services
with no GUI for mac os x?

The service will post data to the webpage with the usual data like geo location & IP
information about the machine so it should be able to access the internet too.

Please lead me to the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [System Startup Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/Introduction.html) a read. Create a command line tool project, not a Cocoa Application nor a Cocoa Document-Based application. To provide a GUI to interface with it you'll want to use a separate application (ideally one you don't have to install with the "hidden" app, since you seem not to want it to be easily discoverable).

With the exception of AppKit (UI) stuff, the rest of the basic Cocoa frameworks is still available to you via the command line. This means you'd write the main logic of your app (the non-GUI parts) the same as you would otherwise.

Comment: Over my 2+ years of being a SO user, not once have any of my edits been approved. So now I just comment.

Comment: I have found that `NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver` never fires when running in a command line console - I think there needs to be something that checks for Cocoa messages and processes them. I have tried blocking the console using `readLine()` and `while(true) { sleep(50) }` without any success

Comment: **UPDATE**: You can do this too by calling `NSApplication().run()`

Answer (score 16):

It's fairly straightforward.

Go to:

Information Property List Key Reference

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html

in the Launch Services Keys, you will see one called "LSBackgroundOnly" simply define this in your Info.plist and set it to true.

```
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<true/>
```

From the documentation:

> LSBackgroundOnly (Boolean - Mac OS X)
>   specifies whether this application
>   runs only in the background. If this
>   key exists and is set to “1”, Launch
>   Services runs the application in the
>   background only. You can use this key
>   to create faceless background
>   applications. You should also use this
>   key if your application uses
>   higher-level frameworks that connect
>   to the window server, but are not
>   intended to be visible to users.
>   Background applications must be
>   compiled as Mach-O executables. This
>   option is not available for CFM
>   applications.

Your application will be a background application.

Comment: -1 This isn't enough. If your application creates any windows, they're still visible.

Comment: @TarkaDaal, Wrong. This is more than enough. The OP specifically said "with no GUI". That means no windows will be created.

Comment: This however results in 

> "Failed to connect (colorGridView) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable; Failed to connect (view) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable"

Comment: In my case, setting `LSBackgroundOnly` to `true` in the Info.plist was sufficient. The only place I was able to spot the running app was in the Activity Monitor, where it appears as a running process. My app also has one window, but this will remain hidden. Using Swift 5 and Xcode 11.6.